# asp:DropDownList server call with out postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I just started with visual basic

some shots of [my code 1](http://content.screencast.com/users/minagabriel/folders/Jing/media/38b37b85-64ad-46f8-9a8b-621d22a1b1f7/2012-08-13_1456.png)
[Code 2](http://content.screencast.com/users/minagabriel/folders/Jing/media/ff08a594-2b48-4365-86f7-1beb1502c826/2012-08-13_1458.png)

I have a `asp:DropDownList` with `AutoPostBack="true"` What the post back does is filling another Dropdownlist depending on the selection.

Here is the code behind that handles the selection of the first Dropdownlist:

```
   Public Sub checklistDropMenuChange(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles checklistDropMenu.SelectedIndexChanged

    If (checklistDropMenu.SelectedValue = -1) Then
        taskDropMenu.Items.Clear()
        taskDropMenu.Enabled = False
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "KeepAddChecklistPopup", "showPopup('addChecklisTaskopup', 'add new Task');", True)
    Else
        taskDropMenu.Enabled = True
        taskList.SelectParameters("lngChecklist").DefaultValue = checklistDropMenu.SelectedValue
        taskDropMenu.Enabled = True
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "KeepAddChecklistPopup", "showPopup('addChecklisTaskopup', 'add new Task');", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

The form is in a popup div , when I do any selection the page post back empty all data I have in the page except the two `DropDownLists`.

Notice I set the `AutoPostBack="true"` to `false` if I select any thisng in the first dropdownlist it doesn't do any thing ?

**Question** how can I fill the second dropdownlist depending on the first dropdown selection and keeping all my data?

Comment: Based on your code screen shots, what is being "reset" after you post back?

Comment: any type of data i have on the page

Comment: Do you have viewstate disabled?

Comment: i don't even know how to do that

Comment: Based on the code you've supplied and the small update I made to your code in my answer, I do not understand how your page does not work.  It looks like you are already using an UpdatePanel... are these cleared items contained within your update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you might have some fun:asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

Answer (score 0):

This will require either a postback or AJAX.  If you're okay with a full-screen refresh, then this will be a fairly easy problem to solve.

Based on your report, it sounds like you might be setting default data in an event handler, and not checking if this is the initial post.  Could you possibly post your Page_Load event handler?

Suggested updated code:

```
Public Sub checklistDropMenuChange(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles checklistDropMenu.SelectedIndexChanged

    If (checklistDropMenu.SelectedValue = -1) Then
        taskDropMenu.Items.Clear()
        taskDropMenu.Enabled = False
    Else
        taskDropMenu.Enabled = True
        taskDropMenu.Items.Clear()
        taskList.SelectParameters("lngChecklist").DefaultValue = checklistDropMenu.SelectedValue
        taskDropMenu.DataBind()
    End If

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "KeepAddChecklistPopup", "showPopup('addChecklisTaskopup', 'add new Task');", True)
End Sub
```

I'm assuming taskList is an ObjectDataSource of some sort?